# Grab focus/text input in editables widget

Tags: javascript, widget, ckeditor

I have a ckeditor widget added with the following code

```
editor.widgets.add('testwidget', {
  editables: {
    content: {
      selector: '.test_widget_content'
    }
  },
  upcast: function(element) {
    return element.name == 'h1' && element.attributes['test_widget_content'] == 'true';
  },
  init: function() {
    this.on('focus', function(ev){
        console.log('focused this');
    });
    this.on('key', function(ev){
        console.log('Keyed this');
    });
}
```

This does add the widget, but the focus and key methods which I set in init, are newer called.

If I remove editables: then key and focus are called as expected, so the question is: How do I listen to focus and key events in an widget which is editables?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out you can just use:

```
this.editables.content.on('keyup',function(ev) {
                    console.log('key up');
                });
```

in the init method. Only thing is that on('key',function() { }) don't work. But keydown and keyup does work.